# Python repeat: Is there a conditional/lambda based repeat method for python?

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following function

```
def handle(x):
    if is_odd(x):
        return x * 3 + 1
    return x // 2
```

and I want to run it repetively feeding the value returned from handle(x) into itself until it returns 1

i.e. handle(...handle(handle(handle(x)))...) until one of them in the chain returns a 1

```
repeat(handle(x), lambda x: x != 1)
```

I want to write something like this:

```
(let n = handle(x) until n != 1)
```

well basically I want to store the output of handle until I get 1.

```
expression(handle(10)) = [5,
                         16,
                         8,
                         4,
                         2,
                         1]
```

Is there a generator expression equivalent of this? or a functools.repeat method I could use for this?

Just to be clear, I would like to avoid directly using a for loop with a yield or recursion. I would like to use python in built features to solve this excluding the for loop/recursion.

Comment: what is the desired output? `handle` does not have side effects and the ultimate return value `1` is known up front... also, the for loops, yield and recursion are all built-in features of python...

Comment: I think I know what you want, can you give the output you expect for, say, handle(10)?

Comment: yes ill clarify the answer

Comment: Is your built-in restriction for the sake of speed? I don't see how calling lambdas in a repeat-like-function-with-an-exit-condition would save you any time compared to using a while loop.

Comment: It is not for speed just out of interest.

Comment: @Aprillion It's very strongly suspected, but not yet proven, that iterating `handle` will eventually return 1 for all initial inputs.

Comment: I suppose what you wanted might be Haskell's `let n = 10:map handle (tail n)`

Comment: @chepner you are not trying to disprove that statement by actually *running* the code, are you? how long would you try to run it if it's not true, for ever and ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `itertools.accumulate` and `itertools.takewhile`, I guess:

```
from itertools import accumulate, takewhile, repeat

def collatz(n):
    seq = accumulate(repeat(n), lambda x,_: handle(x))
    return list(takewhile(lambda x: x!=1, seq)) + [1]
```

which gives

```
>>> collatz(5)
[5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
>>> collatz(17)
[17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

but I share the common view that I don't see the point here.  Even the official documentation lists a lot of [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) which are handy for working with iterables which aren't built-in; I don't see why you couldn't just define something like

```
def repeat_until(fn, x, cond):
    while True:
        yield x
        if cond(x): break
        x = fn(x)
```

and get on with your day.  I know you've said you don't want to use `yield` explicitly for some reason, but just because you say you want something doesn't mean that what you want makes any sense. :-)

Comment: hahaha :) "but just because you say you want something doesn't mean that what you want makes any sense" :) yes but this is what I was looking for Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need no magical methods for working with Collatz Conjecture, just write a regular loop

```
def expression(n):
  result = [n]
  while n > 1:
    n = handle(n)
    result.append(n)
  return result
```

in particular you can make it a generator

```
def expression_gen(n):
  yield n
  while n > 1:
    n = handle(n)
    yield n
```

and obviously you can parametrize it through

```
def expression_gen(n, handle, end):
  yield n
  while not end(n):
    n = handle(n)
    yield n
```

and you can call it with lambda expression as handle/end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here's what I think is the canonical approach using a generator and a while loop.

```
def handle(x):
    while x != 1:
        x = x*3 + 1 if x%2 else x//2
        yield x
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(handle(10))
[5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

The other option which comes close to what you are looking for is to use recursion and the `yield from` syntax, if your Python version supports it:

```
def handle(x):
    if x!= 1:
        x = x*3 + 1 if x%2 else x//2
        yield x
        yield from handle(x)
```

There's a problem with this approach, though, which is blowing up the stack:

```
>>> for x in handle(1E1000): pass
[...]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop :

```
def handle(num):
    while num > 1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num //= 2
            print(num)
        else:
            num = 3 * num + 1
            print(num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handle(10)
```